# Issue with gap bet between two buttons in JQUERY UI

Tags: jquery-ui

I have issue like this:

[image: button gap]
When I place button (...) I get gap like above. I'm using `$('#id').button();`. How can I solve this?

### UPDATE

Now i saw where is an error. On that button I'm setting style(margins top and left) to bee near input filed. If i remove that style button is bellow input field and without gap. Now my question is how to place button near input filed without setting margins?

Comment: How about providing the entire code?

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm new on jsfiddle. There's no jquery ui.. Can I use just jquery?

Comment: see the tab external resources. just add your stylesheet there and update. http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/94Sq6/

Comment: is jqery-ui on my hard drive or link to web page?

Comment: On jsfiddle works, I think... The code above is generated dinamically. I have parent element and then $parrent.append('<input>'). Maybe here is problem...

Comment: Put your answer in an answer so the question can be resolved, or close it, please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved by adding everything in table with one row and 3 columns..